# need to add data in google charts by reading specific xml file using only javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, google-visualization

I am not able to add data in google chart by using data.addRow([name[i],uniqueaudience[i]]). Here name[] and uniqueaudience[] are two global arrays. I am extracting my xml values  to store in these arrays.
also the code for xml values.Here is my code where i am storing xml values in these arrays
i am developing my application in ajax and javascript.

```
 function displayList_websites(xmlhttp,selectedDemographyIndex){
           var items = xmlhttp[selectedDemographyIndex-1].getElementsByTagName("Items");

           txt="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<table id='information' border='1'><thead><tr><th >Rank</th><th>Name</th><th>UniqueAudience</th><th>TrafficePercentage</th></tr></thead>";
           x=xmlhttp[selectedDemographyIndex-1].getElementsByTagName("Items");


           for (i=0; i < x.length; i++)
             {
                       if(i%2 == 0){
                        txt=txt + "<tr>";
                        }
                        else{
                            txt=txt + "<tr bgcolor='#F8F8F8'>";
                            }

             xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("Rank");
               {
               try
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                 }
               catch (er)
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
                 }
               }
               xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("Name");
               {
               try
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td width='50%'>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                 name[i] = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                 }
               catch (er)
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
                 }
               }
               xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("UniqueAudience");
               {
               try
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                 uniqueaudience[i] = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
                 }
               catch (er)
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
                 }
               }
             xx=x[i].getElementsByTagName("TrafficePercentage");
               {
               try
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td>" + xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue + "</td>";
                 }
               catch (er)
                 {
                 txt=txt + "<td> </td>";
                 }
               }
             txt=txt + "</tr>";
             }
           txt=txt + "</table>";
           document.getElementById("lowerRightDiv").innerHTML=txt;


          }
```

Also my code for google chart is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

  function drawChart(){

     for(i = 0;i<name.length;i++)
     {
         alert(name[i]+" "+ uniqueaudience[i]);
     }

     //var years = ['2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005'];
      //var sales = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

     var i,a1,a2,a3,a4;
     var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
     data.addColumn('string', 'name');
     data.addColumn('number', 'uniqueaudience');




            for(i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
                data.addRow([name[i], uniqueaudience[i]]);





        var options = {
          title: "Movies",
          width: 600,height:400


        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('lowerRightDiv'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
  }
      function initialize () {
            $(button.charts).click(function() {
                drawChart();
            });
        }

      </script>
```

Comment: When does `displayList_websites` get called?  Does your `alert` statement the loop inside `drawChart` fire?

Comment: @asgallant Whenever user wants to get topten list of websites,they click on a link, and  displayList_websites() displays topten list in a table according to Rank,Name of websites,No.of audience who used that website and trafficpercentage of that websites.On clicking on the link it makes ajax request to server for the XML file.It all displays fine.Now what i need to do is to display the same information in google charts using name of websites and no.of audience to that website.so i created global arrays.they display correct information in alert.But after coming at data.addRow nothing happens.

Comment: Do i need to use DomParser for reading from xml.I am using xmlhttp.responseXML to read all the elements and its all working fine to diplay information in table format.For using google chart is there any special requirement?